# What does the arxiv.org anti-bot "search and destroy" actually do?

Tags: web, denial-of-service

The [lanl.arxiv.org](http://lanl.arxiv.org/) math and scientific preprint service (formerly known as [xxx.lanl.gov](http://xxx.lanl.gov/)) has a strict policy against bots that ignore its `robots.txt`, [Robots Beware](http://lanl.arxiv.org/RobotsBeware.html). On that page, the have a link labelled with "Click here to initiate automated 'seek-and-destroy' against your site", which is forbidden by their [`robots.txt`](http://lanl.arxiv.org/robots.txt) but presumably badly behaved robots will follow it, and reap the consequences. The question, what are the actual consequences? I have never had the guts to actually click on that link to see what it does. What can they be doing that is both effective and legal?

Comment: Heh, cool... Clicking the link...

Comment: Shucks, just a page that holds the connection open for ages and ages. Nothing too interesting. Hey, why are there men with guns here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [reverse DNS result]: you've been identified as a robot operating in violation of the guidelines posted at arxiv.org.
>
> If this determination is in error, please report to www-admin@arxiv.org so your problem can be investigated.

```
Scanning, Initialized:

10 minutes to Trinity...
9 minutes to Trinity...
8 minutes to Trinity...
7 minutes to Trinity...
6 minutes to Trinity...
5 minutes to Trinity...
4 minutes to Trinity...
3 minutes to Trinity...
2 minutes to Trinity...
1 minute to Trinity...
```

> Ground zero. Have a nice day.
>
> Contact

So... it's a page that would waste 10 minutes of a *very* naive bot's time. Probably useless for combating malicious bots, but might save some bandwidth when faced with a badly-written site-scraper.

Answer (score 0):

No consequences other than spinning for a bit. Most browsers (and probably their server) will just timeout after a bit. They probably just cause more harm to themselves with this than the bots.